# Network error: Software caused connection abort (SSH & FTP) due to IP ban?

Tags: ssh, iptables, putty, fail2ban, ubuntu-16.04

I have been setting up Fail2Ban and ufw. I have added my IP to ufw and fail2ban whitelists, but after simulating mutiple failed ssh login attempts it seems my IP has been banned.

I get the following error message in putty and FileZilla when using the 'banned' IP to attempt a connection: "Network error: Software caused connection abort".

I looked in the fail2ban jail, but there were no active bans. My IP is whitelisted in IP tables yet I cannot attempt a connection over Putty or FileZilla. I tried from another IP and it connects without issues.

Given that I cannot find my IP blocked in IP tables or in the fail2ban jail, what else could cause this? I have tried disabling ufw and rebooting the server multiple times.

Thanks

Comment: could you pls put here the output of `sudo iptables -n -L -v`? Beside would be good idea test with `tcpdump` if the connection from your ip address is established.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with 'denyhosts' that came pre-installed so I was unaware of it. It did not create any entries in iptables, leading to the confusion.